# Vertical Line in Histogram

Tags: plotting, histograms

I created a histogram of my data. This was working fine.

```
plotbootstrap = Histogram[data, 30]
```

I now also want to add a vertical line for a certain $x$ value (here for $x = 0.006$). So far I tried the following commands: `Plot`, `Show`, and `GridLine`. None of these was working. I also defined my line and tried to plot it together with the histogram. This was also not working.

```
line = Line[{{0.0059, 0}, {0.0059, 120}}];
Show[plotbootstrap, line]
```

I hope someone of you may be able to help me.

Comment: This [example](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/VisualizeTheMaximumHeightOfAHistogram.html) should be helpful.

Comment: You can also try `Show[plotbootstrap, Graphics[line]]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.
I already tried it. On this way I get an output but I just see my histogram and not my line. Don't know why

Comment: It worked! By using epilog it was working now. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Write up an answer and post it.  Perfectly fine to answer your own question around here.

Answer (score 3):

I guess, this will help you:

```
plotbootstrap = 
 Histogram[Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/12}], 30, 
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[{{0.1, 0}, {0.1, 3}}]}], {0.1, 
     0}, {0, 0}]]
```

`Epilog` draws you object (in this case it is line) after drawing of the main figure and the `Inset` allows to add anything onto the figure.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason why your strategy of combining a `Histogram` and a `Line` using `Show` shouldn't work,

```
Show[
 Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500], 30],
 Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[{{-1.25, 0}, {-1.25, 30}}]}]]
```

[image]